# C++ Polymorphism error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm trying to pass a child object to a function that accepts its parent object with the code:

```
Rook bRookL();
board[0][0].setPieceObj(bRookL);
```

and I get the following errors:

```
    ChessBoard.cpp:16:35: error: no matching function for call to 'Space::setPieceObj(Rook (&)())'
     board[0][0].setPieceObj(bRookL);
                                   ^
In file included from ChessBoard.h:13:0,
                 from ChessBoard.cpp:5:
Space.h:62:10: note: candidate: void Space::setPieceObj(Piece&)
     void setPieceObj(Piece &);
          ^
Space.h:62:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Rook()' to 'Piece&'
```

Here is my code:

ChessBoard.h:

```
#ifndef CHESSBOARD_H
#define CHESSBOARD_H

#include "Space.h"

using namespace std;

class ChessBoard {

private:
    Space board[8][8]; // board[0][0] is the upper-left corner of the board and
                       // board[7][7] is the lower-right corner of the board

public:
    ChessBoard();

};

#endif /* CHESSBOARD_H */
```

ChessBoard.cpp:

```
#include "ChessBoard.h"
#include "Space.h"
#include "Rook.h"

using namespace std;

ChessBoard::ChessBoard() {

    Rook bRookL();
    board[0][0].setPieceObj(&bRookL);

}
```

Rook.h:

```
#ifndef ROOK_H
#define ROOK_H

#include "Piece.h"

using namespace std;

class Rook : public Piece {

public:
    Rook() : Piece() {

    }

};

#endif /* ROOK_H */
```

Piece.h:

```
#ifndef PIECE_H
#define PIECE_H

using namespace std;

class Piece {

public:
    Piece() {

    }

};

#endif /* PIECE_H */
```

Space.h:

```
#ifndef SPACE_H
#define SPACE_H

#include "Piece.h"
#include "Rook.h"

using namespace std;

class Space {

private:
    Piece *pieceObj;

public:
    void setPieceObj(Piece &);

};

#endif /* SPACE_H */
```

Space.cpp:

```
#include "Space.h"

using namespace std;

Space::Space() {



}

void Space::setPieceObj(Piece &p) {

    pieceObj = p;

}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears, based on the examination of your code, that setPieceObj() should probably take a pointer argument:

```
void Space::setPieceObj(Piece *p) {

    pieceObj = p;

}
```

That's one problem. Now, you need to pass a pointer to a `Piece` object.

```
Rook bRookL();
board[0][0].setPieceObj(&bRookL);
```

That's a [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), that declares a function that returns a `Rook`, and passes a pointer to it, to setPieceObj().

There's not enough information to determine your clear intent. Perhaps:

```
Rook bRook;
board[0][0].setPieceObj(&bRookL);
```

Comment: I changed Rook bRookL(); to Rook bRook; and then changed Piece *pieceObj; to Piece pieceObj; and it compiles. Thank you!

Comment: Eh, not so fast, @user3706950. You need to use pointers. Otherwise you're going to have an [object slicing problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Comment: I will probably use pointers instead, now that I just realized bRookL will go out of scope when the function ends.

Comment: Interesting post on object slicing. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

```
Rook bRookL();
board[0][0].setPieceObj(&bRookL);
```

1.`Rook bRookL();` doesn't do what you expect, it's a declaration of function , which takes no parameters and returns `Rook`, i.e. `Rook (*)()` (just as compiler told you).

2.`&bRookL` will return the address of `bRookL`, so it will be a pointer. But `Space::setPieceObj(Piece &p)` expects its paramter to be `Piece&`. It seems you should change the parameter type to `Piece*` to make them consistent.

Then

```
Rook bRookL;
board[0][0].setPieceObj(&bRookL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointer (`&bRookL`) can't be cast to reference (`Piece&`).

Most likely solution is in declaration of `setPiece` that should take pointer:

```
void setPieceObj(Piece*);
```

Which should actually make definition to be compilable too:

```
void Space::setPieceObj(Piece* p) {
    pieceObj = p;
}
```